# Issue with some very basic arithmetic in apex

Tags: apex

I tried some basic arithmetic in execute anonymous and got some strange outputs. Im hoping someone can help me understand whats going on here:

```
Double test = (16/7);
if(test > 2.0) System.debug('Over 2'); //This doesn't print regardless of what type of number test is
System.debug(test); //This is "2"
```

As I understand it, Any number that isn't an int should have a value of 2.3 or so. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The division operation `(16/7)` is done as integer division as both operands are integers.

What you want is `Double test = 16.0/7.0;`